# RC4 cipher not working on Windows 2008 R2 / IIS 7.5

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, ssl

I have schannel configured to disallow insecure protocols and ciphers as per standard recommendations but I Sslscan only reports AES & 3DES as available cipher options.
Although RC4 should be enabled, and is setup as the preferred cipher, it just doesn't come up as an option.

The schannel registry settings are configured as follows:

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL
  Ciphers
    AES 128/128: Enabled (1)
    AES 256/256: Enabled (1)
    DES 56/56: Enabled (0)
    NULL: Enabled (0)
    RC2 128/128: Enabled (0)
    RC2 40/128: Enabled (0)
    RC2 56/128: Enabled (0)
    RC4 128/128: Enabled (1)
    RC4 40/128: Enabled (0)
    RC4 56/128: Enabled (0)
    RC4 64/128: Enabled (0)
    Triple DES 168/168: Enabled (1)
  Protocols
    PCT 1.0
      Server: Enabled (0)
    SSL 2.0
      Server: Enabled (0)
    SSL 3.0
      Server: Enabled (1)
    TLS 1.0
      Server: Enabled (1)
    TLS 1.1
      Server: DisabledByDefault (0), Enabled (1)
    TLS 1.2
      Server: DisabledByDefault (0), Enabled (1)
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\
```

The output of SSLScan is:

```
Supported Server Cipher(s):
Rejected  SSLv2  168 bits  DES-CBC3-MD5
Rejected  SSLv2   56 bits  DES-CBC-MD5
Rejected  SSLv2  128 bits  IDEA-CBC-MD5
Rejected  SSLv2   40 bits  EXP-RC2-CBC-MD5
Rejected  SSLv2  128 bits  RC2-CBC-MD5
Rejected  SSLv2   40 bits  EXP-RC4-MD5
Rejected  SSLv2  128 bits  RC4-MD5
Failed    SSLv3  256 bits  ADH-AES256-SHA
Failed    SSLv3  256 bits  DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
Failed    SSLv3  256 bits  DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA
Failed    SSLv3  256 bits  AES256-SHA
Failed    SSLv3  128 bits  ADH-AES128-SHA
Failed    SSLv3  128 bits  DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
Failed    SSLv3  128 bits  DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA
Failed    SSLv3  128 bits  AES128-SHA
Failed    SSLv3  168 bits  ADH-DES-CBC3-SHA
Failed    SSLv3   56 bits  ADH-DES-CBC-SHA
Failed    SSLv3   40 bits  EXP-ADH-DES-CBC-SHA
Failed    SSLv3  128 bits  ADH-RC4-MD5
Failed    SSLv3   40 bits  EXP-ADH-RC4-MD5
Failed    SSLv3  168 bits  EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA
Failed    SSLv3   56 bits  EDH-RSA-DES-CBC-SHA
Failed    SSLv3   40 bits  EXP-EDH-RSA-DES-CBC-SHA
Failed    SSLv3  168 bits  EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA
Failed    SSLv3   56 bits  EDH-DSS-DES-CBC-SHA
Failed    SSLv3   40 bits  EXP-EDH-DSS-DES-CBC-SHA
Accepted  SSLv3  168 bits  DES-CBC3-SHA
Failed    SSLv3   56 bits  DES-CBC-SHA
Failed    SSLv3   40 bits  EXP-DES-CBC-SHA
Failed    SSLv3  128 bits  IDEA-CBC-SHA
Failed    SSLv3   40 bits  EXP-RC2-CBC-MD5
Failed    SSLv3  128 bits  RC4-SHA
Failed    SSLv3  128 bits  RC4-MD5
Failed    SSLv3   40 bits  EXP-RC4-MD5
Failed    SSLv3    0 bits  NULL-SHA
Failed    SSLv3    0 bits  NULL-MD5
Failed    TLSv1  256 bits  ADH-AES256-SHA
Failed    TLSv1  256 bits  DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
Failed    TLSv1  256 bits  DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA
Accepted  TLSv1  256 bits  AES256-SHA
Failed    TLSv1  128 bits  ADH-AES128-SHA
Failed    TLSv1  128 bits  DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
Failed    TLSv1  128 bits  DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA
Accepted  TLSv1  128 bits  AES128-SHA
Failed    TLSv1  168 bits  ADH-DES-CBC3-SHA
Failed    TLSv1   56 bits  ADH-DES-CBC-SHA
Failed    TLSv1   40 bits  EXP-ADH-DES-CBC-SHA
Failed    TLSv1  128 bits  ADH-RC4-MD5
Failed    TLSv1   40 bits  EXP-ADH-RC4-MD5
Failed    TLSv1  168 bits  EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA
Failed    TLSv1   56 bits  EDH-RSA-DES-CBC-SHA
Failed    TLSv1   40 bits  EXP-EDH-RSA-DES-CBC-SHA
Failed    TLSv1  168 bits  EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA
Failed    TLSv1   56 bits  EDH-DSS-DES-CBC-SHA
Failed    TLSv1   40 bits  EXP-EDH-DSS-DES-CBC-SHA
Accepted  TLSv1  168 bits  DES-CBC3-SHA
Failed    TLSv1   56 bits  DES-CBC-SHA
Failed    TLSv1   40 bits  EXP-DES-CBC-SHA
Failed    TLSv1  128 bits  IDEA-CBC-SHA
Failed    TLSv1   40 bits  EXP-RC2-CBC-MD5
Failed    TLSv1  128 bits  RC4-SHA
Failed    TLSv1  128 bits  RC4-MD5
Failed    TLSv1   40 bits  EXP-RC4-MD5
Failed    TLSv1    0 bits  NULL-SHA
Failed    TLSv1    0 bits  NULL-MD5
```

Prefered Server Cipher(s):
    SSLv3  168 bits  DES-CBC3-SHA
    TLSv1  256 bits  AES256-SHA

As you can see, RC4 is not accepted as an option.
I've used the same configuration (except for TLS 1.1-1.2) on Windows 2003R2/IIS6 servers before and RC4 hasn't been a problem.

Can anyone help me find why RC4 128/128 is not working?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue why RC4 isn't working is that is has to be set to 0xfffffff or 4294967295 in the registry, not 1 to enable it.

Here's some PowerShell functions which were used to set our IIS installs up with the PCI compliant:

*This function is used to enable/disable required protocols*

```
function Set-IISSecurityProtocols {
$protopath = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols"
& reg.exe add "$protopath\PCT 1.0\Server" /v Enabled /t REG_DWORD /d 00000000 /f
& reg.exe add "$protopath\SSL 2.0\Server" /v Enabled /t REG_DWORD /d 00000000 /f
& reg.exe add "$protopath\SSL 3.0\Server" /v Enabled /t REG_DWORD /d 00000001 /f
& reg.exe add "$protopath\TLS 1.0\Server" /v Enabled /t REG_DWORD /d 00000001 /f
& reg.exe add "$protopath\TLS 1.1\Server" /v Enabled /t REG_DWORD /d 00000001 /f
& reg.exe add "$protopath\TLS 1.1\Server" /v DisabledByDefault /t REG_DWORD /d 00000000 /f
& reg.exe add "$protopath\TLS 1.2\Server" /v Enabled /t REG_DWORD /d 00000001 /f
& reg.exe add "$protopath\TLS 1.2\Server" /v DisabledByDefault /t REG_DWORD /d 00000000 /f
& reg.exe add "$protopath\TLS 1.1\Client" /v Enabled /t REG_DWORD /d 00000001 /f
& reg.exe add "$protopath\TLS 1.1\Client" /v DisabledByDefault /t REG_DWORD /d 00000000 /f
& reg.exe add "$protopath\TLS 1.2\Client" /v Enabled /t REG_DWORD /d 00000001 /f
& reg.exe add "$protopath\TLS 1.2\Client" /v DisabledByDefault /t REG_DWORD /d 00000000 /f
```

}

*And this function is where you set what ciphers are allowed to be used, or not used*

```
function Set-IISSupportedCiphers {
$cipherpath = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers"
& reg.exe add "$cipherpath\NULL" /v Enabled /t REG_DWORD /d 00000000 /f
& reg.exe add "$cipherpath\DES 56/56" /v Enabled /t REG_DWORD /d 00000000 /f
& reg.exe add "$cipherpath\RC2 40/128" /v Enabled /t REG_DWORD /d 00000000 /f
& reg.exe add "$cipherpath\RC2 56/128" /v Enabled /t REG_DWORD /d 00000000 /f
& reg.exe add "$cipherpath\RC2 128/128" /v Enabled /t REG_DWORD /d 00000000 /f 
& reg.exe add "$cipherpath\RC4 40/128" /v Enabled /t REG_DWORD /d 00000000 /f
& reg.exe add "$cipherpath\RC4 56/128" /v Enabled /t REG_DWORD /d 00000000 /f
& reg.exe add "$cipherpath\RC4 64/128" /v Enabled /t REG_DWORD /d 00000000 /f
& reg.exe add "$cipherpath\RC4 128/128" /v Enabled /t REG_DWORD /d 4294967295 /f
& reg.exe add "$cipherpath\Triple DES 168/168" /v Enabled /t REG_DWORD /d 4294967295 /f
& reg.exe add "$cipherpath\AES 128/128" /v Enabled /t REG_DWORD /d 4294967295 /f 
& reg.exe add "$cipherpath\AES 256/256" /v Enabled /t REG_DWORD /d 4294967295 /f
```

}

Once these changes have been set (A reboot is required afaik) you then can set the priority in which the ciphers are used.

To immune the BEAST vulnerability it's reccomended you used RC4 first as outlined @ http://www.phonefactor.com/blog/slaying-beast-mitigating-the-latest-ssltls-vulnerability.php

This will be the case until either

- All browsers patch the BEAST vulnerability
- Or everyone starts supporting TLS1.2